# Anyone know how to display a pandas dataframe in Databricks?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Previously I had a pandas dataframe that I could display as a table in Databricks using:

```
df.display()
```

Pandas was updated to v2.0.0. today and I am now getting the following error when I run df.display():

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

I tried running df.display (without parenthesis) and it gives an output but I am looking for an output in the tabular form.

Comment: A Pandas dataframe, are you sure? Seems to me that `df.display()` is a Spark dataframe method? If you do that on Pandas dataframe, it raises `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'display'`

Comment: does `display(df)` work?

Comment: No none of those techniques work. It seems like the new update to Pandas has messed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, downgrade to pandas v1.5

```
%pip install --upgrade pandas==1.5
```

---

The answers provided till now used to work prior to 3rd April 2023.

As of April 4, with pandas 2.0.0, you are not able to convert a Pandas DataFrame to a Spark DataFrame using the command:

```py
spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Using the above command leads to the error mentioned in the question:

```py
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

The `iteritems` function seems to have been removed in pandas 2.0.0. From the changelog of pandas 2.0.0:

```
Removed deprecated Series.iteritems(), DataFrame.iteritems(), use obj.items instead
```

While the code written in spark to convert pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe still uses `iteritems`

```py
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    308                     warnings.warn(msg)
    309                     raise
--> 310         data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
    311         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    312 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in _convert_from_pandas(self, pdf, schema, timezone)
    340                             pdf[field.name] = s
    341             else:
--> 342                 for column, series in pdf.iteritems():
    343                     s = _check_series_convert_timestamps_tz_local(series, timezone)
    344                     if s is not series:
```

Looks like we will have to wait for a fix to use Pandas 2.0.0.

Comment: Had this exact issue. Had to downgrade to make it work. Not sure when they're going to put out a fix.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `display` function passing Pandas DataFrame as the argument - not try to call it as a member of the Pandas DataFrame class.

```py
display(pdf)
```

[image]

Or you can simply specify variable name with Pandas DataFrame object - then it will be printed using Panda's built-in representation

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pdf = spark.range(10).withColumn("rnd", F.rand()).toPandas()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to convert the pandas dataframe to spark

```
df.createDataFrame(dataframe_pandas)  
df.display()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below lines:

```
    pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items
    df=spark.createDataFrame(df)
    display(df)
```

The newer version of pandas doesn't support 'iteritems'. So, this is the simplest fix for any AttributeError's due to pandas